# Rails cannot load rubygems/defaults file on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, railsinstaller

Versions, dependencies, and other information:

- Ruby: 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
- Rails: 3.2.13
- Gemfile located at: http://pastebin.com/z9u40Jca

For some reason, whenever I run any gem based command, it gives me this error:

```
$ rails s
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:30:in `require': cannot l
oad such file -- rubygems/defaults (LoadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:30:in `<top
(required)>'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I have tried deleting ruby 2.0.0 from pik and the rails installer folder, because another SO thread said that would fix it. The commands were working as of 5 hours ago, and must have stopped right when I finished using the rails console (part of learning rails from this tutorial, it was just basic math and string manipulation, so I don't think I screwed something up). Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting 'ruby '1.9.3' ' from your gem file.  It shouldn't be causing a problem, but I've seen situations where it has.

Comment: It didn't do anything. Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: did you run bundle install after deleting it?

Comment: Yes, and when that happens it takes a loooong time to "resolve dependencies," even though it didn't use to do that. I let it sit for two hours, uninterrupted, and it was still un-resolved.

Comment: Then something is definitely wrong with the gem file.  The only suggestion i have is to separate your :test and :development blocks.  So have one :test block and one :development block, and repeat gems if necessary.  This isn't the proper way, but if it works you'll have an idea of what to fix.

Comment: Um, I'm new to rails, and ruby in general, but I don't understand. Aren't the blocks already separated? They each have their own do/end block in my gemfile.

Comment: I just realized, are you in the right directory?  What directory are you running commands in?

Comment: I am running all of my commands in the directory for the rails app. Would it change anything knowing that I reinstalled rails using the windows railsinstaller to fix the problem first sparking this question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I did something I don't know about, but to the best of my knowledge, adding the gem "bootstrap-sass" at version 2.3.2.0 got it working again. I doubt that it was adding that exact gem that was the solution, but you never know.